# Fire an Outlook 2003 macro when the user creates a new blank message

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003

I found events that fire when the user receives a message, or hits the send button, but nothing that fire when the user creates a blank, new email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the NewInspector event.  Example:

```
Public WithEvents myOlInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Initialize_handler
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlInspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub myOlInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set msg = Inspector.CurrentItem

        If msg.Size = 0 Then
            MsgBox "New message"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly after I enabled macros. The 'high' security setting in Outlook 2003 doesn't even give you the option to run unsigned macros, so switching to 'medium' did the trick.