# Add automatically CC In the new message in outlook using VBA doen't appear?

Tags: vba, outlook

when i click new email outlook the automatically cc email doesn't appears form VBA code in cc text area please help me in doing this i already add the CC using VBA in Application_ItemSend event but it appears after message send i want to show up the CC when the user click New Message in outlook ribbon..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for post your code for more clarity.

```
    strcc = "xxx@yyy.com"
    Dim objRecip As Recipient
    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strcc)
    objRecip.Type = olCC
        If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
        strMsg = "Could not resolve the cc recipient. " & _
        "Do you want still to send the message?"
        res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
        "Could Not Resolve cc Recipient")
            If res = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    Set objRecip = Nothing`
```

Comment: gives me debug error  Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
  strcc = "xxx@yyy.com"
    Dim objRecip As Recipient
    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strcc)
    objRecip.Type = olCC
        If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
        strMsg = "Could not resolve the cc recipient. " & _
        "Do you want still to send the message?"
        res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
        "Could Not Resolve cc Recipient")
            If res = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    Set objRecip = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: i already do this but the problem when i click new message the text area for the cc appears empty i want to display the "xxxx@yyy.com" in the cc before i send it ....

Answer (score 0):

See the NewInspector event example here

[Fire an Outlook 2003 macro when the user creates a new blank message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674832/can-i-fire-an-outlook-2003-macro-when-the-user-creates-a-new-blank-message/3680546#3680546)

```
Public WithEvents myOlInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Initialize_handler
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlInspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub myOlInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set msg = Inspector.CurrentItem

        If msg.Size = 0 Then
            MsgBox "New message"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```