# How to make a outlook VBA macro work every time i click on compose "new mail"?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this module for outlook:

```
Sub NewMessageWithAttachment()
    Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Set oMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With oMsg
        .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\Vinicius\image"
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

But everytime i want to run it, requires to press f5 or start it, is there anyway i can make it run automatically every time that i press to compose a new mail ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041614/trigger-function-to-run-when-a-user-starts-writing-a-new-email-in-outlook-vba

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fire an Outlook 2003 macro when the user creates a new blank message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674832/fire-an-outlook-2003-macro-when-the-user-creates-a-new-blank-message)

Answer (score 1):

There is an `Application_ItemLoad` event which you could use, but it would be a bit more complex than you might like - you'd need to filter down the `Item` argument to only Mail Items, and then there's the added complication that within that procedure most of the `Item` properties are not accessible.

To get around the property access problem you can cache the object in a global variable and set a short Windows Timer to call a sub to process the item (adding the attachment if you find it looks like a new unsent mail object)

In `ThisOutlooksession`:

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
        Set NewLoadedItem = Item
        StartTimer
    End If
End Sub
```

modHandleItemLoad"

```vb
Option Explicit
Public NewLoadedItem As MailItem

Sub ProcessLoadedItem()
    If NewLoadedItem Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    With NewLoadedItem
        'check here and add the attachment if appropriate
    End With
    Set NewLoadedItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

modTimer:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
    ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Public TimerID As Long

Sub StartTimer()
    TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, 500&, AddressOf TimerProc)
End Sub

Sub EndTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    KillTimer 0&, TimerID
End Sub

Sub TimerProc()
    EndTimer 'stop the timer
    ProcessLoadedItem
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can repurpose the corresponding ribbon button. So, when a user clicks on the ribbon button for creating a new email your event handler will be triggered before. See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.

Another approach for handling reply, replyall and forward events is to handle the [SelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selectionchange) event of the `Explorer` class. So, you will be aware which item is currently selected in the Explorer window and will be able to subscribe to the item-level events. You may find the [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event like that available in the [`Outlook.Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/Concepts/Getting-Started/using-outlook-visual-basic-for-applications-to-respond-to-outlook-events) object. The closest thing I could find is on [`MailItem.Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.write) event. This would allow you to attach at save, or autosave, before a mailitem is sent. You can also capture the [`.Send`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.send(even)) event.

Answer (score 0):

Already got;

```
Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If (TypeOf Item Is MailItem) Then
        Set myItem = Item
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    myItem.Subject = ""
    myItem.To = ""
    myItem.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\Public\Documents\teste.xlsx"

End Sub
```

it'll cancel the create new mail event, and instead open a personalized one with the attachment.